# Multinomial Naive Bayes for OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv, naivebayes, pattern-recognition

I'm looking for a **Multinomial Naive Bayes classifier** written in **C/C++** for use with **OpenCV**.

I'm looking for the **Algorithm** (or a readymade implementation) as it will be more helpful as I'm trying to understand on how it works?

Comment: What's Google take on this subject?

Comment: There's something [here](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Normal_Bayes_Classifier_in_CSharp), but I'm not sure it's the same algorithm you are looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Naive Bayes Classifier is a well-known classification algorithm. especially in the field of text classification, so I will take it for explaining.

Assuming we have some training document `{d1 , d2 , d3 , ... , dm}` where each document can be represented by a collection of words `{w1,w2,w3, ... , wn}`
and each document belongs to some predefined set of class (take binary case `(c_0,c_1)` here)
Our task is to classify some new input document d into either class `c_0` or class `c_1`.

An intuitive way would be to take maximum likelihood estimation:
      that is,

```
output c_0 if P(d | c_0) > P(d | c_1) and vice versa.
```

so by our definition of d, we can write the criterion by

```
P(d | c_0) = P( {w1,w2,w3...,wn}  | c_0)
```

since calculating this joint probability given class is so complicated. So we make a strong assumption that words are mutually independent conditioned on class.
So that leads us to

```
P(d | c_0) = P({w1,w2,w3...,wn} | c_0) = P(w1|c_0)*P(w2|c_0)*P(w2|c_0)...*P(wn|c_0)
```

where each `P(w | c)` can be easily computed as frequency count of word w in class c.

this strong assumption is the reason for the name "Naive", since we just naively do series multiplication for each word.

finally taking `answer = argmax P(d | c_0) , P(d | c_1)`  would end this algorithm

I guess in your domain what you're looking is similar to text classification, except the feature you need to extract is different.